# copy on OSX server preserving posix & acl

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I am looking to move my fileserver from one xserve to a new one. Both are bound to the same open directory master.
I am having trouble copying and preserving all of the posix and acl permissions. 
I have done it in the past with
`tar -pcvf` but I would really like to do it without creating a 4tb tar file and extracting it.

Currently I have one server mounted to the other via AFP.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do it is via rsync, not AFP… & not Apple's rsync either, but at least 3.0.7 or up.  You can get it via MacPorts or lots of other ways, but make sure it's your default rsync on both systems by either prepending it to your $PATH or specify --rsync-path.  Here's a set of flags I've found to work the best:

`rsync -avHNAX --progress --fileflags --force-change src dst`

Comment: Hm. Does installing macports alone add the newer version or rsync or do you have to download an rsync port separately?

Comment: You install MacPorts, then do `sudo port install rsync`.